# How to cumulatively track unique combinations by group in R

Tags: r, count, data.table, unique

I have observations with unique identifiers that are associated with one or more `START`/`END` date pair. These observations are iterated per ID by month within the date range. An example for one unique ID and category, truncated for length.

```
  ID       START        END    MONTH CAT.A
10056 2004-01-08 2005-01-07 Jan 2004 
10056 2004-01-08 2005-01-07 Feb 2004 
10056 2004-01-08 2005-01-07 Mar 2004 
...
10056 2004-01-08 2005-01-07 Nov 2004 
10056 2004-01-08 2005-01-07 Dec 2004 
10056 2004-01-08 2005-01-07 Jan 2005 
--------------------------------------
10056 2006-11-28 2008-02-20 Nov 2006 
10056 2006-11-28 2008-02-20 Dec 2006 
10056 2006-11-28 2008-02-20 Jan 2007 
...
10056 2006-11-28 2008-02-20 Dec 2007 
10056 2006-11-28 2008-02-20 Jan 2008 
10056 2006-11-28 2008-02-20 Feb 2008 
--------------------------------------
10056 2010-01-30 2011-02-03 Jan 2010 
10056 2010-01-30 2011-02-03 Feb 2010 
10056 2010-01-30 2011-02-03 Mar 2010 
...
10056 2010-01-30 2011-02-03 Dec 2010 
10056 2010-01-30 2011-02-03 Jan 2011 
10056 2010-01-30 2011-02-03 Feb 2011
```

The solution I am looking for would cumulatively count each unique event occurrence of `CAT.A`. In the first date range `CAT.A` would be 1, increment `CAT.A` to 2 in the second date range, and 3 in the third. This counter would be unique to this ID and be `NA` otherwise

```
  ID       START        END    MONTH CAT.A
10056 2004-01-08 2005-01-07 Jan 2004 1
10056 2004-01-08 2005-01-07 Feb 2004 1
10056 2004-01-08 2005-01-07 Mar 2004 1
...
10056 2004-01-08 2005-01-07 Nov 2004 1
10056 2004-01-08 2005-01-07 Dec 2004 1
10056 2004-01-08 2005-01-07 Jan 2005 1
--------------------------------------
10056 2006-11-28 2008-02-20 Nov 2006 2
10056 2006-11-28 2008-02-20 Dec 2006 2
10056 2006-11-28 2008-02-20 Jan 2007 2
...
10056 2006-11-28 2008-02-20 Dec 2007 2
10056 2006-11-28 2008-02-20 Jan 2008 2
10056 2006-11-28 2008-02-20 Feb 2008 2
--------------------------------------
10056 2010-01-30 2011-02-03 Jan 2010 3
10056 2010-01-30 2011-02-03 Feb 2010 3
10056 2010-01-30 2011-02-03 Mar 2010 3
...
10056 2010-01-30 2011-02-03 Dec 2010 3
10056 2010-01-30 2011-02-03 Jan 2011 3
10056 2010-01-30 2011-02-03 Feb 2011 3
```

The dataset has millions of other unique IDs and 11 other categories, but if I can find a solution for this subset, I should be able to apply it to the entire dataset.

I've found solutions that will let me count the total number of unique combinations of `ID`,`START`,`END`, but nothing that will help increment A in each observation once only when it belongs to a new unique `START`,`END` event.

I have been using data.table and lubridate.

Comment: What have you actually tried using data.table and lubridate?  Can you give a code sample / reproducible version of your data?

Comment: @DavidKlotz I only mentioned it, perhaps extraneously, as the main libraries I've been using while working with my dataset, not necessarily for this issue. The answer by Michael Ohlrogge below should work. I may have been staring at my dataset for so long that I didn't think about reducing it to a simpler example like below. I will give it a shot when I get back into the office tomorrow and reply back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
d = data.table(
    ID = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)),
    CAT = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,3,4)
    )

d[, N_Unique := cumsum(!duplicated(CAT)), by = ID]

> d
    ID CAT N_Unique
 1:  1   1        1
 2:  1   1        1
 3:  1   1        1
 4:  1   2        2
 5:  1   2        2
 6:  2   1        1
 7:  2   1        1
 8:  2   2        2
 9:  2   3        3
10:  2   4        4
```

If you then wanted a separate column for each value of ID (which seems quite odd, given that you have millions of unique values), you could use something like this:

```
d[, ID := as.factor(ID)]
> cbind(d, diag(d[,N_Unique]) %*% model.matrix(~ ID - 1, d))
    ID CAT N_Unique ID1 ID2
 1:  1   1        1   1   0
 2:  1   1        1   1   0
 3:  1   1        1   1   0
 4:  1   2        2   2   0
 5:  1   2        2   2   0
 6:  2   1        1   0   1
 7:  2   1        1   0   1
 8:  2   2        2   0   2
 9:  2   3        3   0   3
10:  2   4        4   0   4
```

Comment: Or `d[, N_Unique := .SD[, rep(.GRP, .N), CAT], by = ID]`. Using `.GRP` would give a different answer for a data-set not ordered by `CAT` within `ID` though.

Comment: @MichaelOhlrogge Your solution at the top helped me obtain my final output by category using
    `d[!is.na(A),A_TOT:=cumsum(!duplicated(EVENT)),by=ID]`

and then repeated for each other category. I had to create `EVENT` by utilizing rleid on my non-iterated dataset:

    `c[,EVENT:=rleid(START),by=.(ID,CATEG)]`

Comment: @DavidLee Great, glad to hear it.